# How to record the difference between consecutive cells over a Range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a functioning macro that copy pastes the static values of live data from the live data sheet (Sheet), onto a separate sheet (Sheet2) every second. The code is below. For your information, Range("B2:B2195") are stock codes while Range("H2:H2195") are stock quotes.

```
Sub copypaste_RECENT()

Dim ab As Integer



Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:B2195").Copy


With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    ab = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Time"
    .Cells(ab, 1).Value = Now


    Worksheets("Sheet").Range("H2:H2195").Copy
    .Range("B" & ab).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True


End With


Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "copypaste_RECENT"

End Sub
```

My next step is one that im having trouble with. I would like to record the difference between the stock quotes. This means calculating the difference between a certain cell and the cell above it and recording this difference onto a separate sheet (Sheet3). This would run simultaneously to the code above so I've tried to include an additional code after End With and before the Application. The code is below.

```
Worksheets("Sheet").Range("B2:B2195").Copy

With Sheets("Sheet3")

    .Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

    Dim xy As Long, yz As Long

    ab = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    bc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(x1toleft).Column + 1


    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Time"
    .Cells(ab, 1).Value = Now

    xy = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row
    yz = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row.Offset(-1, 0)


    For ab = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row + 1
    For bc = 1 To Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(x1toleft).Column + 1
        .Cells(ab, bc).Value = xy - yz
    Next ab
    Next bc



End With
```

I'm quite new to VBA and I know this is completely wrong. I've been struggling for a while but I hope it makes some sort of sense.

Thanks in advance!

Grant

EDIT1: This is a simple computation that calculates the difference between a certain cell and the cell above it and records this value onto a separate sheet. This computation is done for every cell in the range.

Answer (score 0):

I am not comletely cleat what you like to achieve. Is it alog, so you write consecutive lines of copied and computed  entries, or is is just some computation. So depending on this you have at least three options:

1) copy/paste with math functions

using the copy/past with the special mathematical functions (add, substract, multiply, divide)

2) formulas

you enter in sheet3 the formuala into B2 =+sheet2!B4-sheet2!B3 which will compute this automatically.

3) compute an store the difference

make a computation as above and copy/paste the result to the final destination.

**EDIT**

Excel is designed to do computations! So why do you want to redo this?

You can do all of the mentioned solutions as VBA. The same way as you did is with your copy and paste above.

Here is a short makro which shows what I mean.

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Line 1"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "8"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Line 2"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "15"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "456"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "23"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "42"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "45"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "77"
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B2:G2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlSubtract, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe it's just some computation. I think i've been trying option 3. But i've probably overcomplicated it... Because the macro is continuous, i think i still require a VBA code rather than just excel mathematical functions